# Unable the connect the live sql server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, connection, database-connection

I had the secured database sql server. I can't access the server using the php file connectivity.

The code

```
$myServer = "ippaddress";
$myUser = "XXXXXXX";
$myPass = "XXXXXXX";
$myDB = "XXXXXXX";
$conn = mssql_connect($myServer,$myUser,$myPass);
print_r($conn);
if (!$conn) { 
     die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} 
$db_selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $conn);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}
```

And I tried this format of connect code also

```
$serverName = "serverName\instanceName"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxxx", "UID"=>"xxxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo
```

Every time I get an error:

> page isn’t working" and "co.in is currently unable to handle this request.

Where I made mistake?

Comment: what is the PHP version? first use mysqli_* function or PDO...

Comment: **Stop** using `mysql_*` API. It is deprecated and removed in the actual php version. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: @naga PHP Version 5.6.24

Comment: 1) Read above comments and do changes.
2) Make a test.php file and put your code inside it and run it. if run successfully then this error comes up due to some other file.